# Drawing on canvas with js array, not displaying last rows

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I apologize in advanced if I make any mistakes while asking this question, I'm fairly new to stackoverflow and coding.
Basically, I'm trying to draw a game map on a canvas using an array and tileset image with Javascript. I found code for this purpose but for some reason it won't display the last four rows of the array. I've looked at the array over and over looking for mistakes that might cause this but I can't find any. When I inspect it with the Chrome developer tools I get the following error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined test.js:38" which may be related. I can't really imagine it is but then I don't know why it thinks something is undefined in the first place.

I can't for the life of me get the code in my test file to work on codepen so I've uploaded it to my git repository and included the links here. I hope this is okay as I thought including the raw code would be problematic.

https://github.com/AureliaWarleader/farmSimGame/blob/master/test.html
https://github.com/AureliaWarleader/farmSimGame/blob/master/test.js

Thanks in advance for any and all advice and again I apologize if my ignorance is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma at [line 19 at test.js](https://github.com/AureliaWarleader/farmSimGame/blob/master/test.js#L19):

```
[0, 0, 33, 34, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 44, 36, 37, 38],
//                                                                            ^
```

Comment: Hahaha, that's wonderful! I feel like such a jerk but it's always something simple that I just miss. Thanks so much for pointing this out to me and I apologize for wasting time with my frivolous mistake.

Comment: @AureliaWarleader. The built in developers tools (often F12) will help you catch these kind of typos.

Comment: Thanks! I use developer tools but sadly I still didn't see the missing comma. The error pointed to the following line but even reading through the whole array I still missed it. It was simply human error on my and my eye's part.